# BootStrapTour Events

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-tour

I'm trying to prevent the "next" button from going to the next step if a condition on the page hasn't been met (trying to make the tour interactive).  However, nothing i try seems to interrupt the tour from continuing.

Documentation on this is sparse so searching hasn't really yielded anything useful.  My step currently looks like this:

```
{
  path: "/Product/Search",
  title: "Try it!",
  content: "Enter a brief search such as &quot;camera&quot; and pick an item from a list.",
  placement: "top",
  element: "form",
  backdrop: "true",

  onShow: function(t) {
    $("div.form-actions").hide();
  },

  onNext: function (tour) {
     var loc$ = $("#Search");
     if (loc$.val() === '') {
       alert('Enter a search term and pick a location.');

       //Want something (anything) to cancel the click here
       tour.setCurrentStep(tour.getCurrentStep() - 1);


     } else {
        //tour.next();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `return false;`? I really haven't worked with the library but that seems like a possible way to stop the event

Comment: @koala_dev - no change.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
    if(true)
      tour.goTo(5)
    else
      tour.goTo(4)
```

hopefully solves your problem.